# Timestamp comparison in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

Considering below file, how can I compare two timestamps, noting that the time part is negligible.

```
foo,boo,2038-01-18T12:00:00+02:00
foo,boo,2015-09-12T01:31:24+03:00
foo,boo,2015-08-04T03:15:38+03:00
```

I tried to make it by `substring` the date using below code and compare it with other dates *i.e:* `2015-08-12`

```
awk -F, '{$3=substr($3,1,10)}{if($3<2015-08-12){print $0}}'
```

But it did not work.

Desired output:

```
foo,boo,2015-08-04T03:15:38+03:00
```

OR:

```
foo,boo,2015-08-04
```

Comment: You need to quote strings in awk: `if ($3 < "2015-08-12")`

Comment: In your last couple of awk questions, you seem to be writing awk code like C code. Your awk can be more idiomatic. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140173/4667 for some discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to double quote the date, to force string comparison:

```
$ awk -F, '$3 < "2015-08-12"' <file
foo,boo,2015-08-04T03:15:38+03:00
```